# C++ When will be allocated memory in new object?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, constructor, dynamic-allocation

I want to write a class, which can hold 9 variables (physcial values). 
5 of that should be there every time, but I want to control the other 4 with a flag (optional).

**My question is:** If I have 4 variables in the private sector of the class which I do not use... Will be allocated memory for these? If yes: How can I avoid it?

I want to allocate the memory for the optional variables dynamic.

Comment: Please add your code.

Comment: You can add a single pointer to an array with the optional variables, that you either keep `nullptr` or allocate when you need it. This will only cost you one pointer extra. Or you can create subclasses.

Comment: I'd say if you have to ask this question then you should not worry about avoiding memory allocations.

Comment: I would add (to what CompuChip said), you gain memory only if your "optionnal" variables are not primitives types (or are bigger than the pointer size)

Comment: For a given *instance* of your class, do you ever need to be able to switch on the optional elements, or do you know that at the point of construction?

Comment: You can create a new class (or struct) containing those four variables, and keep a pointer to an object of that type in your class. Then you can use the pointer itself as the flag: if it's NULL, you'll know the 4 values aren't there. Or, put the variables in a vector and check the vector's length to see if all 9 values are there.

Comment: @Bathsheba point of construction

Comment: @D.Mogwitz Ah. Two classes then, one base class with 5 values, one descendant with 4 more.

Comment: I'm going to delete my answer since I'm convinced the best thing to do is use one class, and ignore the variables you don't need. Don't overcomplicate the solution.

Comment: @Bathsheba That looked good. But why do you think it is better to ignore the 4 variables. My problem: I have a big grid with a millions of points. First I will read in a file. Now (on the point of construction) I want to decide if I just need the 5 variables or also the other 4... If I do not need these, they allocate memory redundant in millions of points. I do not think that it is better to ignore in my case. Or?

Comment: I think you should try it the extravagant way, and if it's a problem then revert to another approach.

Comment: This was a question... I am really uncertain. A double is 8 Byte. Four doubles 32 Byte. And then for every point in memory allocating the memory... Do you really think that your way was inconvenient? It is better just to ignore the variables?

Comment: @D.Mogwitz if you allocate 1M objects with an additional 32 bytes, that costs you approximately 32MB in memory (forgetting about alignment and such). Is that really a problem on your modern machine with min. 4GB RAM? Or are you running this embedded on a 1024kB RAM device?

Comment: @CompuChip In average we have 16GB RAM. But I thought if you have this overhead for millions of points, it could be bad. Do I think false?

Comment: @D.Mogwitz you may be right, or not. In general, go with the simple, readable solution and measure. If you find the result is unacceptable, _then_ optimize where it matters most.

Answer (score 0):

For those 4 variables, you need to declare member variables as pointers which are initialized as NULLs in constructors. Then you allocate and deallocate those upon your need, don't only forget to surelly deallocate those upon class descrution. However, if your intention is only a memory gain, you need to evaluate the sizeof of those variables against sizeof of pointers to them whether it is benefitial. Normally it has sense only for complex large data types, or to do not expose header files. In 32-bit platforms, those 4 variables will require 4*4=16 bytes only for the pointers, even when they are not used. Plus the memory consuming by the content those pointers point to when they are used.